# Change color of y axis label in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I draw a figure in plotly (python). To change the label color of y axis in the plot I used the code `fig.update_yaxes(color='white')` and `fig.update_layout(font_color="white")` but unfortunately both of them  didn't work, what else can I do?

My code:

```
        for index, i in enumerate(values):
            fig_1.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[today], y=[i], mode='markers', name=names[index], marker_symbol='star-triangle-up', marker_size=15))

        fig_1.update_layout(
            xaxis_title="",
        )

        fig_1.update_layout( height=450, width=700,xaxis_title="", plot_bgcolor='rgba(65, 104, 119, 0.8)',   )                   
        fig_1.update_layout(legend=dict(
            yanchor="top",

            y=0.99,
            xanchor="left",
            x=0.01,
            )
                    )
        fig_1.layout.yaxis.color = 'white'

        fig_1.update_xaxes(color='white') 
        fig_1.update_yaxes(color='white')
```

[image]

Comment: what was the output that you got? changing the color using `fig.update_yaxes(color='white')` seems to be working for me, but the font is not visible since it blends in with the background. Please provide the code that you used and what version of plotly that you are using to make solving your problem easier.

Comment: Plotly version is `4.14.3`

Comment: @AS11, I added my code and screenshoot of the output.

Comment: I think problem is in python which is in my machine. When I run the code in jupyter it works fine but when I run it on my machine it didn't change the colo of y axis. What can be the reason?

Comment: I use plotly offline, Can it be reason for this problem?

Comment: When I write fig.show() it displays correct, when I use plotly offline it don't consider color for tick labels

Comment: From what I can find, some of the things have changed from plotly offline from version 3, so that may be a cause for the issue, but I can not find exactly what could be the issue. I would reccomend just using `fig.show()`, and if your use case requires offline, I think doing a little bit of research should be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
fig.update_yaxes(title_font_color="red")
```

You can look [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-title-font-color) for more settings.